# How to find issues added to active sprint in JIRA?

Tags: jira, jql

We use corkboard with printed Agile Cards. I would like to be able to **create filter in JIRA's Issue Navigator to find issues that were added to the active sprint in the last 24 hours, last 2 days, etc**. That way I wouldn't have to manually select new issues for printing everyday.

I've tried to write JQL query for this, but I only got this far:

```
project = "Our Project"
AND sprint = 1002
AND (created >= -1d OR (updated >= -1d AND status WAS Open BEFORE -1d))
```

This is not satisfying because:

1. Sprint id isn't automatically selected (activeSprint() or something similar).
2. Query doesn't actually answer my question.

Comment: #1 "sprint in openSprints()" might help you

Comment: @rcourtna why do you write that up as an answer?

Comment: There is a change request at Atlassian to allow 'historical operators' (`WAS`, `WAS NOT`, ...) to work with the `Sprint` field. [Here's the link, in case you want to upvote it](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-39256).

Comment: @Jir upvoted, thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 21):

You can find issues in the current open sprint with the JQL clause:

```
sprint in openSprints()
```

Comment: But sadly there is no history of the sprint value supported.

Comment: this will return all future sprints results as well.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question at all - it could be useful for something... but not for what the requester asks for

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve what you asked for using the [standard JQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching), I think you'll have to create your own JQL search, check [Adding a JQL Function to JIRA](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Adding+a+JQL+Function+to+JIRA) for how-to.

Another option would be using one of Jira's [remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) to manually get the issue list.

Comment: That would select all the issues which status changed in whatever way (also the ones which went from "In progress" to "In review"). Issues in the backlog have "Open" status, so does the ones in "To Do" list. So this query would not select issues added to the sprint in the last 24h.

Comment: History searches do not support the 'sprint' field.

Comment: didn't think so but though to give it a try, only i don't have this plugins so i can't test it myself. well than, seems like you'll have to do some programming to get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Adaptavist extension, then you can do this:

```
project = "Our Project"
AND sprint in OpenSprints()
AND issueFunction in addedAfterSprintStart("<the name of your scrum board>")
AND (created >= -1d OR (updated >= -1d AND status WAS Open BEFORE -1d))
```

The key is to leave out the second parameter, the sprint number, of the addedAfterSprintStart function.